# ScyllaDB-4.0.3 compiled on centos 7-aarch64

Tags: centos7, arm64, scylla

I compiled the source code of ScyllaDB-4.0.3 on centos 7-aarch64,I had some problems.

when I typed './install-dependencies.sh', then the output of the console like this:

No package **rh-mongodb36-boost-devel** available.

Package devtoolset-8-gcc-c++-8.3.1-3.2.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

No package **devtoolset-8-libubsan** available.

No package **devtoolset-8-libasan** available.

No package **devtoolset-8-libatomic** available.

Nothing to do
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn
- centos-sclo-rh: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn
- centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn
- epel: mirrors.yun-idc.com
- extras: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn
- updates: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn

Package 1:yaml-cpp-devel-0.5.1-2.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

Package thrift-devel-0.9.1-15.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

No package **scylla-antlr35-tool** available.

No package **scylla-antlr35-C++-devel** available.

Package jsoncpp-devel-0.10.5-2.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

Package snappy-devel-1.1.0-3.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

Package rapidjson-devel-1.1.0-2.el7.noarch already installed and latest version

No package **scylla-boost163-static** available.

No package **scylla-python34-pyparsing20** available.

Package systemd-devel-219-73.el7_8.8.aarch64 already installed and latest version

Package pigz-2.3.4-1.el7.aarch64 already installed and latest version

where can i download these dependeces like rh-mongodb36-boost-devel、devtoolset-8-libubsan、devtoolset-8-libasan、devtoolset-8-libatomic、scylla-antlr35-tool、scylla-antlr35-C++-devel、scylla-boost163-static and scylla-python34-pyparsing20?

I had tried ways to fix these problems, but failed.

Has anyone ever compile scylladb on centos 7-aarch64 and know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The default build runs on latest Fedora. If you like to build on centos,
best is to use the docker builder which users Fedora to build Scylla in it and then you can use the relocatable binary in centos